# Como desagrupar as transações ou agrupar por dia?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

```
SELECT 
       COUNT(*) QTD_TRANSACOES,
       CD_RSP_RECUSA,
       SUM(VL_AUTORIZADO) VALOR_SOMATORIO,
       CASE WHEN
                    MR.DS_MOTIVO_RECUSA IS NULL THEN 'CÓDIGO DE RECUSA NÃO CADASTRADO'


       WHEN
             MR.DS_MOTIVO_RECUSA = 'APROVADO' THEN 'TRANSAÇÃO DECLINADA'
       ELSE
             MR.DS_MOTIVO_RECUSA 
       END
              MOTIVO_RECUSA
FROM   PRD_BI.DBO.TB_AUTORIZACAO T WITH (NOLOCK) 
LEFT   JOIN PRD_RELATORIOS.TRANSACAO.TB_MOTIVO_RECUSA MR WITH (NOLOCK)
ON     T.CD_RSP_RECUSA = MR.CD_MOTIVO_RECUSA
WHERE   TP_AUTORIZACAO = 'D'
AND     CD_AUT = ''
AND     DT_AUTORIZACAO BETWEEN '20170501' AND '20170531'
GROUP BY CD_RSP_RECUSA,MR.DS_MOTIVO_RECUSA
```

- Como verificar se faltou cargas no mês de maio de 2017?
- E como desagrupar as transações ou agrupar por dia(maio)?

Comment: Informe a estrutura das tabelas e, caso seja possível, os dados disponíveis em cada uma delas

Comment: Alguma resposta ajudou a resolver o problema e pode sanar dúvidas similares de outros usuários? Caso positivo não esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o `WITH` para gerar os dias disponíveis do mês e vinculá-los com sua `query` original:

```
WITH dias
AS (
  SELECT CAST('2017-05-01' AS DATE) AS dia,
         1 AS nivel
   UNION ALL
  SELECT CAST(DATEADD(DAY, 1, dia) AS DATE),
         nivel + 1
    FROM dias
   WHERE dia < '2017-05-31'
)
SELECT COUNT(*) AS QTD_TRANSACOES,
       CONVERT(VARCHAR, D.DIA, 103) AS DIA,
       CD_RSP_RECUSA,
       SUM(VL_AUTORIZADO) AS VALOR_SOMATORIO,
       CASE
         WHEN MR.DS_MOTIVO_RECUSA IS NULL THEN 'CÓDIGO DE RECUSA NÃO CADASTRADO'
         WHEN MR.DS_MOTIVO_RECUSA = 'APROVADO' THEN 'TRANSAÇÃO DECLINADA'
         ELSE MR.DS_MOTIVO_RECUSA 
       END AS MOTIVO_RECUSA
  FROM PRD_BI.DBO.TB_AUTORIZACAO T WITH (NOLOCK) 
       INNER JOIN DIAS D ON D.DIA = T.DT_AUTORIZACAO
       LEFT JOIN PRD_RELATORIOS.TRANSACAO.TB_MOTIVO_RECUSA MR WITH (NOLOCK) ON T.CD_RSP_RECUSA = MR.CD_MOTIVO_RECUSA
 WHERE TP_AUTORIZACAO = 'D'
   AND CD_AUT = ''
   AND DT_AUTORIZACAO BETWEEN '2017-05-01' AND '2017-05-31
 GROUP BY CD_RSP_RECUSA, MR.DS_MOTIVO_RECUSA, D.DIA
```