# Imprimir dias do mês na tabela

Tags: sql, sql-server

Eu estou tentando criar um relatório baseado em algumas tabelas do meu banco, nesse relatório, eu preciso passar durante o mês, em qual dia a operação foi executada, logo, preciso imprimir todos os dias do mês, e compará-los com o meu campo de `dataExecutada`.

esta é minha tabela atual

[image: Tabela incompleta]

Este é o relatório esperado:

[image: Relatório esperado]

Dos campos que tem nesse relatório eu só não tenho as datas do mês

Só falta passar os dias do mês e comparar com o meu `initDate`.

Como posso fazer para adquirir esse tipo de informação na minha `query`? Segue meu código atual:

```
SELECT DISTINCT vapacasset,
                awp.workprocedure,
                wp.workprocedurename,
                awp.intervaltype,
                assetwp.initdate,
                CONVERT(VARCHAR, assetwp.dateinterval) + CONVERT(VARCHAR(1), CASE
                                                                                          WHEN assetwp.intervaltype = '2' THEN 'M'
                                                                                          ELSE 'D'
                                                                                        END) AS PERIOD
  FROM asset a
 INNER JOIN assetworkprocedure awp
    ON a.asset = awp.asset)
 INNER JOIN workprocedure wp
    ON awp.workprocedure = wp.workprocedure)
 INNER JOIN v_assetparentassetcl vapac
    ON awp.asset = vapacasset
 WHERE vapacparentasset = 'F.SP.SPO.IP'
   AND awp.recordstate = 'OP'
```

[image: [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdaYM.png]

Comment: Relacionada: [Dividir intervalo de datas em semanas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/221907/dividir-intervalo-de-datas-em-semanas/221927#221927).

Comment: Relacionada: [Como desagrupar as transações ou agrupar por dia?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/217534/59479).

Comment: Eu preciso passar a tabela igual está na segunda foto, selecionar todos os dias do mes (este virá como parâmetro do meu backend), e comparar o dia que for compatível com `initDate` de asset, que já está sendo selecionado na query atual

Comment: @Sorack fiz as edições solicitadas

Comment: Alguma resposta ajudou a resolver o problema e pode sanar dúvidas similares de outros usuários? Caso positivo não esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).

Answer (score 0):

A melhor forma de fazer o que você deseja seria direto na linguagem de programação em que está gerando o relatório. Porém no banco você pode criar uma função que gere um registro para cada dia do intervalo que você informar e retornar isso em uma coluna da sua `query`:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('imprimir_intervalo', 'FN') IS NULL
BEGIN
  EXEC('CREATE FUNCTION imprimir_intervalo() RETURNS INT AS BEGIN RETURN 1 END');
END;
GO

ALTER FUNCTION imprimir_intervalo(@inicial DATE,
                                  @dias    INT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @texto VARCHAR(MAX);

  WITH dias AS (
      SELECT @inicial AS dia,
           1 AS quantidade
       UNION ALL
      SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, dia),
           quantidade + 1 AS quantidade
          FROM dias
       WHERE quantidade < @dias
    )
  SELECT @texto = ISNULL(@texto + ', ', '') + CAST(DATEPART(DAY, d.dia) AS VARCHAR)
    FROM dias d;

  RETURN @texto;
END;
GO
```

Uma execução de exemplo:

```
SELECT dbo.imprimir_intervalo(getdate(), 2)
```

Que resulta em:

> ```
> 13, 14
> ```

Aplique na sua regra de negócio como necessitar.